# single page flip jquery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have been searching for a single page flip jquery plugin just like the jflip (not book like interface). The problem with the jflip is that it reads only images from a document but i need other contents also to be read. I've been googling big time for the plugin but in vain. Do I need to code my own plugin or is there something I need to modify the jflip plugin to read other contents? Are there similar plugins?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This one will be helpful - http://www.turnjs.com/